# Не исключает чего или что?

Tags: согласование

*Такое конструктивное исполнение комбинированной прокладки не исключает повторное использование прокладки при условии замены пластичного уплотнителя.*

Допустимо ли такое согласование или надо написать "не исключает повторного использования"? И как будет согласовываться это предложение, если добавить слово "возможность"? *Не исключает возможности повторного использования* или *не исключает возможность повторного использования*?

Answer (score 3):

**Лучше использовать Р.п.**

Такое конструктивное исполнение комбинированной прокладки не исключает **повторного использования**. Не исключает **возможности** повторного использования.

**У Розенталя:** Р.п. применяется при выражении дополнения **отвлеченными существительными:** не дает оснований, не обнаруживает понимания, не теряет надежды, не скрывает радости, не осуществляет контроля, не упускает случая, не делает уступок. Например: Здесь шума не любят (Горький); Веселья я не ищу (В. Кетлинская); Утро не принесло ясности (Леонов); [XLV. УПРАВЛЕНИЕ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm)

Comment: Спасибо. Но тем не менее и использование именительного грубой ошибкой не является?.. В Нацкорпусе, правда, тоже на где-то на восемь совпадений родительного два именительных...

Comment: На слух вообще довольно сложно сделать правильный  выбор , правила носят рекомендательный характер, поэтому грубой ошибкой, я думаю, не является. Р.п. - книжный, отвлеченный,  усиленное отрицание, В.п. - разговорный, конкретный, ослабленное отрицание. Но это основные факторы, есть еще дополнительные, кто с этим будет разбираться. Поэтому неудивительно, что в речи встречаются оба падежа.